# Error "unbalanced parenthesis" on regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to solve the challenge [Count the Smiley Faces](https://edabit.com/challenge/gfo2RDnW7atsvQqnY)  from edabit.com and have this code:

```
import re
def count_smileys(lst):
    pat = "[:;]?[-~]?[)D]?"
    res = []
    for i in lst:
        if re.fullmatch(i, pat):
            res.append(i)
    return len(res)
```

However this is throwing an error

> "sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis."

I have tested regex with RegExr and it works fine. What is causing this error?

Comment: The `)` is used for grouping in regular expressions. To match the actual character it has to be escaped: `\)`

Comment: You also need to use `re.fullmatch(pat, i)`.

Comment: @KlausD. Nope, when in the `[...]`, the `)` does not have to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You have confused the pattern with the string. Change `re.fullmatch(i, pat)` to `re.fullmatch(pat, i)`